# Why are some transaction receipt decoded logs transfer values off by 1000000000?

Tags: web3js

I'm working through some example transactions and inspecting logs to get some data. Specifically how many tokens were gained as the result of a transaction. Looking at transactions on UniswapV3 and UniswapV2 I'm getting the result I expected and it matches the overview data of etherscan. However when I look at transactions from PancakeSwap or SushiSwap the "amount of tokens" as a result of the transaction is consistently off by 1000000000 (exactly 1 billion?).

Mostly I'm wondering what the cause of this is so I can account for it in the code I'm writing.

Comment: Can you show the transaction hash where it happened?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without a specific example, but my best guess is that you are looking at a token that does not have 18 decimals.

If you look at the amount in wei, then it will look off compared to the same token if it had 18 decimals.